# how to insert ajax result json format into Datatable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, table

```
$.ajax({
    url: "apex/demopage",
    success: function(resp) {

    }
})
```

//and my resp coming as follows

```
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "something",
            "url": "something"
        },
        "fname": "something",
        "lname": "something"
    },
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "something",
            "url": "something"
        },
        "fname": "something",
        "lname": "something"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In datatable, you can customize [columns](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) data to specify which property to use for columns. Here is an example below:

```
// JSON structure for each row in this example:
//   {
//      "engine": {value},
//      "browser": {value},
//      "platform": {value},
//      "version": {value},
//      "grade": {value}
//   }
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajaxSource": "sources/objects.txt",
  "columns": [
    { "data": "engine" },
    { "data": "browser" },
    { "data": "platform" },
    { "data": "version" },
    { "data": "grade" }
  ]
} );
```

For additional details, refer:

1. [Ajax data source (objects)](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html)
2. [Nested object data (objects)](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/deep.html)